# How to use `sum` within `summarize` in a KQL query?

Tags: sum, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-log-analytics, kql

I'm working at logging an Azure Storage Account. Have a Diagnostic Setting applied and am using Log Analytics to write KQL queries.

My goal is to determine the number of `GetBlob` requests (`OperationName`) for a given `fileSize` (`RequestBodySize`).

The challenge is that I need to `sum` the `RequestBodySize` for all `GetBlob` operations on each file. I'm not sure how to nest `sum` in `summarize`.

**Tried so far:**

```
StorageBlobLogs
| where TimeGenerated >= ago(5h)
  and AccountName == 'storageAccount'
  and OperationName  == 'GetBlob'
| summarize count() by Uri, fileSize = format_bytes(RequestBodySize)
| render scatterchart
```

**Results in:**

[image]

**Also tried:** `fileSize = format_bytes(sum(RequestBodySize))` but this errored out.

Any ideas?

**EDIT 1:** Testing out @Yoni's solution.

- Here is an example of `RequestBodySize` with no summarization:

[image]

- When implementing the summarize query (`| summarize count() by Uri, fileSize = format_bytes(RequestBodySize)`), the results are `0 bytes`.
- Though its clear there are multiple calls for a given Uri, the sum doesn't seem to be working.

[image]

**EDIT 2**:

- And yeah... pays to verify the field names! There is no `RequestBodySize` field available, only `ResponseBodySize`. Using the correct value worked (imagine that!).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to sum the `RequestBodySize` for all `GetBlob` operations on each file

If I understood your question correctly, you could try this:

```
StorageBlobLogs
| where TimeGenerated >= ago(5h)
  and AccountName == 'storageAccount'
  and OperationName  == 'GetBlob'
| summarize count(), total_size = format_bytes(sum(RequestBodySize)) by Uri
```

Here's an example using a dummy data set:

```
datatable(Url:string, ResponseBodySize:long)
[
    "https://something1", 33554432,
    "https://something3", 12341234,
    "https://something1", 33554432,
    "https://something2", 12345678,
    "https://something2", 98765432,
]
| summarize count(), total_size = format_bytes(sum(ResponseBodySize)) by Url
```

| Url | count_ | total_size |
| --- | --- | --- |
| https://something1 | 2 | 64 MB |
| https://something3 | 1 | 12 MB |
| https://something2 | 2 | 106 MB |

Comment: Thank you for the idea. `sum` is still not aggregating. Please see **EDIT 1** above.

Comment: I've extended the answer by showing a valid output for a valid input. i don't have access to your data set, but i'd recommend you try to verify the validity of the input first

Comment: Thank you for the continued engagement. Aside from verifying that `RequestBodySize` has an INT showing before summarizing, how do I validate the input? **EDIT 2** above shows a valid INT with no summarization.

Comment: And.... yeah. Slap myself! The parameter name is `ResponseBodySize` (not `RequestBodySize` !).

Comment: I had been working with querying the other side of transactions (`PutBlob` operations) before this which does use the `RequestBodySize` parameter.